# hyperref trouble with natbib citation inside of tabular

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib

I'm using `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` to create pdf documents. Using `natbib`'s `\cite` command inside of a `tabular` environment, I run into trouble that `hyperref` does not creates a box reference around the citation but only "underlines" it. Without `natbib` everything works fine. `pdflatex` also works fine. Even outside of `tabular` `natbib` works fine. What could be the reason for this strange behavior?..

Here a minimalistic example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}


\begin{document}

\cite{miranda:1999:3581}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    \cite{miranda:1999:3581}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\bibliography{papers_litstudy_diplexer}
\bibliographystyle{plain}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: LaTeX output]

Answer (score 4):

This happens with the `pdfmark` drivers (`dvips`, `dvipsone`, ...). There are two main ways to generate a link:

- `\hyper@link`: The link is put into a box and the rectangle is measured.
- `\hyper@linkstart`...`\hyper@linkend`: At the begin of the link a PostScript special is written and at the end, when the link is created, the width can be measured. But the height of the link is not known and `\baselineskip` is used as approximation.

In case of `natbib` and `\cite` the latter method is used. However, `\baselineskip` is zero inside a `tabular`. Therefore the link rectangle is shrunk to a "line".

As workaround, the `\baselineskip` can be set explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{miranda:1999:3581}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{10pt}%
    \cite{miranda:1999:3581}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{miranda:1999:3581}Miranda.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Now everything looks the way it should! :) Also, I made some improvement on your method to make it work more general:  `\newlength{\tabbaselineskip}`   `\setlength{\tabbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}`  `\begin{tabular}{|@{\strut\hspace{\tabcolsep}\setlength{\baselineskip}{\tabbaselineskip}}c|}`  Now there is no need to put `\setlength{\baselineskip}{\tabbaselineskip}` before every citation cince all the citations belong in the same column for me. Also I added a `\strut` to make the table look nicer :)))